# Why is unsquash not permitted to create symlink and certain files?

Tags: debian, ubuntu, squashfs

I try to alter a `debian` live iso to activate the `sshd` according to this [guide](https://www.dotpointer.ga/?section=notes&view=note&id_notes=164).

This is done on a Ubuntu 20 in a virtualbox on a macOS High Sierra.

When I `unsquashfs -f -processors 1 filesystem.squashfs` I get errors for symlinks and also for some files. Is this due to my host system not permitting the symlink or is this a problem with unsquash?

Snippet of errors:

```
create_inode: failed to create symlink squashfs-root/etc/alternatives/lzegrep.1.gz, because Operation not permitted

create_inode: failed to create symlink squashfs-root/etc/alternatives/lzfgrep, because Operation not permitted

create_inode: failed to create symlink squashfs-root/etc/alternatives/lzfgrep.1.gz, because Operation not permitted

create_inode: failed to create symlink squashfs-root/etc/alternatives/lzgrep, because Operation not permitted

create_inode: failed to create symlink squashfs-root/etc/alternatives/lzgrep.1.gz, because Operation not permitted

create_inode: failed to create symlink squashfs-root/etc/alternatives/lzless, because Operation not permitted

create_inode: failed to create symlink squashfs-root/etc/alternatives/lzless.1.gz, because Operation not permitted

create_inode: failed to create symlink squashfs-root/etc/alternatives/lzma, because Operation not permitted

create_inode: failed to create symlink squashfs-root/etc/alternatives/lzma.1.gz, because Operation not permitted

create_inode: failed to create symlink squashfs-root/etc/alternatives/lzmore, because Operation not permitted

create_inode: failed to create symlink squashfs-root/etc/alternatives/lzmore.1.gz, because Operation not permitted

create_inode: failed to create symlink squashfs-root/etc/alternatives/mail, because Operation not permitted

create_inode: failed to create symlink squashfs-root/etc/alternatives/mail.1.gz, because Operation not permitted

create_inode: failed to create symlink squashfs-root/etc/alternatives/mailx, because Operation not permitted

create_inode: failed to create symlink squashfs-root/etc/alternatives/mailx.1.gz, because Operation not permitted

create_inode: failed to create symlink squashfs-root/etc/alternatives/messages, because Operation not permitted

create_inode: failed to create symlink squashfs-root/etc/alternatives/messages.1.gz, because Operation not permitted

create_inode: failed to create symlink squashfs-root/etc/alternatives/movemail, because Operation not permitted

create_inode: failed to create symlink squashfs-root/etc/alternatives/movemail.1.gz, because Operation not permitted

create_inode: failed to create symlink squashfs-root/etc/alternatives/mt, because Operation not permitted

create_inode: failed to create symlink squashfs-root/etc/alternatives/mt.1.gz, because Operation not permitted

create_inode: failed to create symlink squashfs-root/etc/alternatives/my.cnf, because Operation not permitted

create_inode: failed to create symlink squashfs-root/etc/alternatives/nawk, because Operation not permitted

create_inode: failed to create symlink squashfs-root/etc/alternatives/nawk.1.gz, because Operation not permitted

create_inode: failed to create symlink squashfs-root/etc/alternatives/open, because Operation not permitted
[|                                                                                     ]     47/256001   0%
create_inode: failed to create symlink squashfs-root/etc/alternatives/open.1.gz, because Operation not permitted

create_inode: failed to create symlink squashfs-root/etc/alternatives/pager, because Operation not permitted

create_inode: failed to create symlink squashfs-root/etc/alternatives/pager.1.gz, because Operation not permitted

create_inode: failed to create symlink squashfs-root/etc/alternatives/pico, because Operation not permitted

create_inode: failed to create symlink squashfs-root/etc/alternatives/pico.1.gz, because Operation not permitted

create_inode: failed to create symlink squashfs-root/etc/alternatives/pinentry, because Operation not permitted

create_inode: failed to create symlink squashfs-root/etc/alternatives/pinentry-x11, because Operation not permitted

create_inode: failed to create symlink squashfs-root/etc/alternatives/pinentry-x11.1.gz, because Operation not permitted

create_inode: failed to create symlink squashfs-root/etc/alternatives/pinentry.1.gz, because Operation not permitted

create_inode: failed to create symlink squashfs-root/etc/alternatives/rcp, because Operation not permitted

create_inode: failed to create symlink squashfs-root/etc/alternatives/rcp.1.gz, because Operation not permitted

create_inode: failed to create symlink squashfs-root/etc/alternatives/readmsg, because Operation not permitted

create_inode: failed to create symlink squashfs-root/etc/alternatives/readmsg.1.gz, because Operation not permitted

create_inode: failed to create symlink squashfs-root/etc/alternatives/regulatory.db, because Operation not permitted

create_inode: failed to create symlink squashfs-root/etc/alternatives/regulatory.db.p7s, because Operation not permitted

create_inode: failed to create symlink squashfs-root/etc/alternatives/rlogin, because Operation not permitted

create_inode: failed to create symlink squashfs-root/etc/alternatives/rlogin.1.gz, because Operation not permitted

create_inode: failed to create symlink squashfs-root/etc/alternatives/rmt, because Operation not permitted

create_inode: failed to create symlink squashfs-root/etc/alternatives/rmt.8.gz, because Operation not permitted

create_inode: failed to create symlink squashfs-root/etc/alternatives/rsh, because Operation not permitted

create_inode: failed to create symlink squashfs-root/etc/alternatives/rsh.1.gz, because Operation not permitted

create_inode: failed to create symlink squashfs-root/etc/alternatives/rview, because Operation not permitted

create_inode: failed to create symlink squashfs-root/etc/alternatives/sar, because Operation not permitted

create_inode: failed to create symlink squashfs-root/etc/alternatives/sar.1.gz, because Operation not permitted

create_inode: failed to create symlink squashfs-root/etc/alternatives/uim-toolbar, because Operation not permitted

create_inode: failed to create symlink squashfs-root/etc/alternatives/unlzma, because Operation not permitted

create_inode: failed to create symlink squashfs-root/etc/alternatives/unlzma.1.gz, because Operation not permitted

create_inode: failed to create symlink squashfs-root/etc/alternatives/vendor-logos, because Operation not permitted

create_inode: failed to create symlink squashfs-root/etc/alternatives/vi, because Operation not permitted

create_inode: failed to create symlink squashfs-root/etc/alternatives/vi.1.gz, because Operation not permitted

create_inode: failed to create symlink squashfs-root/etc/alternatives/vi.da.1.gz, because Operation not permitted

create_inode: failed to create symlink squashfs-root/etc/alternatives/vi.de.1.gz, because Operation not permitted

create_inode: failed to create symlink squashfs-root/etc/alternatives/vi.fr.1.gz, because Operation not permitted

create_inode: failed to create symlink squashfs-root/etc/alternatives/vi.it.1.gz, because Operation not permitted

create_inode: failed to create symlink squashfs-root/etc/alternatives/vi.ja.1.gz, because Operation not permitted

create_inode: failed to create symlink squashfs-root/etc/alternatives/vi.pl.1.gz, because Operation not permitted

create_inode: failed to create symlink squashfs-root/etc/alternatives/vi.ru.1.gz, because Operation not permitted

create_inode: failed to create symlink squashfs-root/etc/alternatives/view, because Operation not permitted

create_inode: failed to create symlink squashfs-root/etc/alternatives/view.1.gz, because Operation not permitted

create_inode: failed to create symlink squashfs-root/etc/alternatives/view.da.1.gz, because Operation not permitted

create_inode: failed to create symlink squashfs-root/etc/alternatives/view.de.1.gz, because Operation not permitted

create_inode: failed to create symlink squashfs-root/etc/alternatives/view.fr.1.gz, because Operation not permitted

create_inode: failed to create symlink squashfs-root/etc/alternatives/view.it.1.gz, because Operation not permitted

create_inode: failed to create symlink squashfs-root/etc/alternatives/view.ja.1.gz, because Operation not permitted

create_inode: failed to create symlink squashfs-root/etc/alternatives/view.pl.1.gz, because Operation not permitted

create_inode: failed to create symlink squashfs-root/etc/alternatives/view.ru.1.gz, because Operation not permitted

create_inode: failed to create symlink squashfs-root/etc/alternatives/write, because Operation not permitted

create_inode: failed to create symlink squashfs-root/etc/alternatives/write.1.gz, because Operation not permitted

create_inode: failed to create symlink squashfs-root/etc/alternatives/x-cursor-theme, because Operation not permitted

create_inode: failed to create symlink squashfs-root/etc/alternatives/x-session-manager, because Operation not permitted

create_inode: failed to create symlink squashfs-root/etc/alternatives/x-session-manager.1.gz, because Operation not permitted

create_inode: failed to create symlink squashfs-root/etc/alternatives/x-terminal-emulator, because Operation not permitted

create_inode: failed to create symlink squashfs-root/etc/alternatives/x-terminal-emulator.1.gz, because Operation not permitted
[/                                                                                     ]     53/256001   0%
create_inode: failed to create symlink squashfs-root/etc/alternatives/x-window-manager, because Operation not permitted

create_inode: failed to create symlink squashfs-root/etc/alternatives/x-window-manager.1.gz, because Operation not permitted

create_inode: failed to create symlink squashfs-root/etc/alternatives/x-www-browser, because Operation not permitted

create_inode: failed to create symlink squashfs-root/etc/alternatives/x-www-browser.1.gz, because Operation not permitted

create_inode: failed to create symlink squashfs-root/etc/alternatives/xinput-ja_JP, because Operation not permitted

create_inode: failed to create symlink squashfs-root/etc/alternatives/xinput-ko_KR, because Operation not permitted

create_inode: failed to create symlink squashfs-root/etc/alternatives/xinput-zh_CN, because Operation not permitted

create_inode: failed to create symlink squashfs-root/etc/alternatives/xinput-zh_HK, because Operation not permitted

create_inode: failed to create symlink squashfs-root/etc/alternatives/xinput-zh_SG, because Operation not permitted

create_inode: failed to create symlink squashfs-root/etc/alternatives/xinput-zh_TW, because Operation not permitted
[\                                                                                     ]     81/256001   0%
FATAL ERROR:write_file: failed to create file squashfs-root/etc/apt/apt.conf.d/01autoremove-kernels, because Operation not permitted
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried to do this inside the shared folder from the virtual machine - because this was how I put the original ISO in.

Once I moved the stuff to another directory everything worked out.

**Creation of symlinks is forbidden in a Windows host and apparently also in macOS:**

https://superuser.com/questions/446362/why-cant-i-create-soft-link-on-vboxsf-file-system#446908